# How to store multiple rows values in single table with single id

Tags: php, sql, mapping, primary-key

I want to save multiple rows with  single id store in table. What should I do? Please guide me.

**For example:**

```
|      table1     |
|-----------------|
|id      |name    |
|001(pk) |Ajit    |

|      table2     |
|-----------------|
|id(FK)  |address |
|001     |Pune    |
|001     |Mumbai. |
```

means **TWO TABLES** are their in **table1 id** is **primary key** & **table2 id** is **foreign key**

i.e.: **001 id** should multiple address it would be save into **table2** but **id** must be same,

i.e.: address textbox  will generate at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Put its(id) default value as "001"(you deserve it) using mysql query and then while inserting a new entry leave that column to add as new.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to link the data in the two tables (i.e. a users table and an addresses table) just use a foreign key.

Your `users` table:

```
id | name
================
1  | Martin Bean
```

Your `addresses` table:

```
id | user_id | address
==================================
1    1         Newcastle upon Tyne
```

This way, the primary key of your `addresses` table is not dependent on the ID of the `users` table. And your query to fetch both pieces of data is easy with a join:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    a.address
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN
    addresses a ON u.id = a.user_id
```